# Function i'm calling is not accessing child class's function through Polymorphism

Tags: c++

I'm making a Pacman game where I have several classes which include, Board (Does all the job through its pointer), Chase (which is inherited from Ghosts). Now I've made a virtual function of 'chase' in Ghosts which is overridden in its children i.e Chase class. Also, in the Board I've Ghosts array of Objects (which is of size four obviously). I have also made a 'chase' function in Board which actually calls the first ghost's chase, which will in turn (*this is where I'm confused*) go into its child's class to be accessed. Kindly help me with this because it's not working as I want it to.

I would like to give a thorough explanation here: 
1) Through Board's class pointer I do almost all the work. This means that my Ghosts class is COMPOSED in my Board class. Board has a function of chase, in which a GHOST object calls its VIRTUAL chase function. 
2) Chase CLASS is derived from Ghost class and contains a chase function as well. 
I have to call this Chase CLASS chase function through the pointer of board.

```
  Ghosts(int x = 0, int y=0)
 {
  protected:

   x_pos = x;
   y_pos = y;

 }

 virtual void chase(char bD)
 {
 }


 class Chase : public Ghosts
 {


  public:
Chase() :Ghosts(){}
void chase(char bD)
{   
        // access x_pos;
        // access y_pos;

}

 class Board {
 private:    

Ghosts G[4];

public:
    void Chase(char bD)
{
    G[0].chase(bD); 
 }
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You can not access child class's function using parent class's object . You've to access it using child class object only. You can access all parent class's public/protected  functions using object of child class.

Comment: I din'nt understand the question... but i can offer one advice... let the object do what the object is thought for... what's the Chase class purpouse? 
Why Ghosts is a Board property?

Comment: You need to describe your problem more completely. Read the "how to ask" link posted above. Also make an effort to get your terminology correct. "Chase (which is inherited from Ghosts)" - you mean it _derives_ from `Ghosts`? "in the Board I've Ghosts array of Objects" - what on earth does this mean? Write your question clearly, and you are more likely to get an answer. Most importantly: " it's not working as I want it to" - describe how it _is_ behaving, and exactly how that differs from how you want it to behave.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read, as well as being incomplete.

Comment: @davmac Yes it 'derives' from ghosts. By "Ghosts array of Objects", I meant there are four ghosts or an array of ghosts of size four. (Remember Ghosts is a class).

I would like to give a thorough explanation here:

1) Through Board's class pointer I do almost all the work. This means that my Ghosts class is COMPOSED in my Board class. Board has a function of chase, in which a GHOST object calls its VIRTUAL chase function.

2) Chase CLASS is derived from Ghost class and contains a chase function as well. 
I have to call this Chase CLASS chase function through the pointer of board.

Comment: @chillax: Your `Board` class contains an array of `Ghost` objects, not `Chase` objects. That is why your code is not calling the `Chase::chase()` overridden method. To use polymorphism, change your array to hold `Ghost*` pointers that point to `Chase` objects instead of `Ghost` objects.

Answer (score 2):

your problem resides with understanding how to use polymorphism,
polymorphism works on reference and on pointers in your case it's neither.
let's explore it:

```
 class A {
  public: 
  virtual ~A() {};
  virtual void chase(char bd) { cout << "A chases : "<< bd << endl; }
```

};

```
class B : public A {
 public:
 void chase(char bd) override { cout << "B chases : " << bd << endl; } 
};
```

in main or w/e:

```
A a, *aptr;
B b;
a.chase('s');
b.chase('s');
aptr = &b;
aptr->chase('s');
a = b;
a.chase('s');
A &ref = b;
ref.chase('s');
```

... will yeild:
A chases : s

B chases : s

B chases : s

A chases : s

B chases : s

why? in those two polymorphism was never used it's a "regular objects"
a.chase('s'); 
b.chase('s');

aptr = &b;  <-we gave aptr the address of a b object 
since chase is virtual now polymorphism kicks in
aptr->chase('s');

same goes with references:
aptr = &b;
aptr->chase('s');

but what you did was actually this: 
a = b; here b copies it's "A" part into a but since a can't hold the "B" part
it doesn't hold it as far as it concern it thinks of b as an A object
a.chase('s'); so that will yield the A chase and not the B chase

so tips: polymorphism can be used with: pointers(smart pointers or raw pointers like i used in my example) or reference. 
if you wanna use polymorphic powers it will do iff you used pointers/references

another tip is use override to notice the compiler that you're overriding a "parent" function it will help you when you have bad parameters and etc( will produce proper compiler error and etc.

and one of the most vital things is always make your destructor in the base class virtual to make sure no zombies will appear

Answer (score 2):

Your `Board` class contains an array of `Ghost` objects, not `Chase` objects. So `G[0].chase(bD);` will always call `Ghost::chase()`, never `Chase::chase()`.  Just because you *define* an override in `Chase` does not mean it is used automatically everywhere a `Ghost` is used.  Polymorphism only works when you have a pointer/reference of a base class type pointing at an object of a derived type.  Your code does not have that.  To fix that, make your array hold `Ghost*` pointers that point at `Chase` objects.  For example:

```
class Board
{
private:    
    Ghosts* G[4];

public:
    Board()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            G[i] = new Chase;
    }

    ~Board()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            delete G[i];
    }

    void Chase(char bD)
    {
        G[0]->chase(bD); 
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that! 
Just one more thing, I'm assigningthe four ghosts their initial position through the Board constructor, like this:

`Board():G{ {11,18}, {13,21}, {15,18}, {13,18} }`

Which can not be done by making `Ghost*`, so any solution to that?